# Пропадает .htaccess

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, сделал архив на винде (winrar) с сайтом, разархивирую его в ubuntu 16.04 и пропадает папка .git, но это не беда, также пропали все файлики .htaccess. Подскажите как можно разархивировать без потери файлов?

Comment: Скорее всего, файлы не пропали, а они просто не видны по умолчанию. Есть такое правило для файлов, начинающихся с точки.

Comment: А как их отобразить, также когда удалил папку с разархивированным сайтом, в корзине выбивала ошибка (типа не может открыть или отобразить)

Comment: если смотрите под GUI, нажмите Ctrl+H. В консоли 'ls -a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка в начале файла или каталога по умолчанию его скроет.

В стандартном файловом менеджере `Nautilus` показать скрытые файлы или папки можно сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl+H` или `View` -> `Show hidden files`